# If the minimal polynomial of a matrix splits, then $A-\lambda I$ maps some vector outside an invariant subspace inside the space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Suppose that $A$ is an operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over some field and its minimal polynomial splits into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors. Suppose $U$ is a proper $A$ invariant subspace of $V$. Then I'm trying to show that there is a vector $x\not\in U$ such that $(A-\lambda I)x\in U$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.

My solution is as follows. Since $U$ is proper, we can pick a vector $x$ outside it. Suppose the minimal polynomial splits as product of $\prod_{j=1}^i(x-\lambda_i)$. If $(A-\lambda_1I)x\in U$, we're done as $x$ was chosen outside $U$. If not, choose $(A-\lambda_1I)x$ as the new $x$ outside $U$ and apply $A-\lambda_2I$. Continue in this fashion. If at any stage we're done, the proof is complete. Otherwise we get to $ \prod_{j=1}^{i}(A-\lambda_i)x=0\in U$. But $\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(A-\lambda_iI)x$ is not in $U$ (since otherwise, we wouldn't have got to this stage) and so, we're still done.

My question is, is this correct? I didn't use the fact that $A$ is invariant on the subspace $U$, but I can't find a flaw with my argument. Thank you for your help.